# Will an Access 2019 .accdb file work in Access 2007?

Tags: microsoft-access

My client is going to send me an Access 2007 .accdb file. Then I am going to make some code changes to that .accdb file using Access 2019. When I send it back to my client will the updated file still work in his Access 2007?

Comment: Microsoft may provide more reliable answers than we can.  That said, I really doubt that MS tested this scenario.  If no one else knows and you do find out, yes or no, please provide an Answer later.

Comment: Access 2019 supports Access 2010 files, but Access 2010 compatible with an Access 2019 file, cannot be guaranteed.  Have you tried to load your Access 2019 file in Access 2010?